# Python: How to Combine (concat) Multiple Excel Files into One File? (Not append)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

Every department completes an annual budget in Excel and submits the budget.  The individual budgets get rolled up into a single master budget.

I've used file linking Excel formulas in the past but, this can be very time-consuming and prone to human error.

I think this is a perfect job for Python with Pandas (and/or other libraries).

Here is a picture sample data:

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far: (edited/cleaned-up a little from the original)

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import glob

# import excel files
path = '*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(path)

# loop thru
combined_files = pd.DataFrame()
for i in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(i, index_col=None, skiprows=11,
                       nrows=147, usecols='D:P')
combined_files = combined_files.concat(df)

combined_files.to_excel('output4.xlsx', index=False)
```

*If I run print(files) the files are listed*

I've also played around with variations of the "combined_excels" variable but no joy.

Desired output:

A spreadsheet or .csv that has the general ledger description, (ie, "supplies"), in the first column, followed by combined amounts from all files under; Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.

So if dept1 budgets for $100 in supplies in January, dept2 budgets $200 in supplies in January, and dept3 budgets for $400 in supplies in January then the result will say: Supplies: Under January will be: $700.

I will have approximately 65 different Excel files and will need to iterate over the list.  Most workbooks have multiple sheets. All of the worksheets have a sheet called, "Budget" and that is where we pulled from.

I removed all supporting sheets from my three sample files so I wouldn't have to deal with that aspect yet, but I will need to add that filter back soon.

I appreciate any help you can provide!

John

Comment: Why not Excel's builtin VB macro functionality?

Comment: Thanks, @randomer64 but I am trying to use python. I see a great value in Python for automating Excel tasks and using this to solve a problem and learn at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code ad your loop thru and concat:

```
# Budget Roll-up
# Used to roll-up individual budgets into one master budget

#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import glob

# import excel files
path = '*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(path)

# loop thru
combined_files = pd.DataFrame()
for i in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(i, index_col=None,
                       skiprows=11, nrows=147, usecols='D:P')
    df.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: 'test'}, inplace = True)
    df.set_index('test', inplace=True)
    combined_files = combined_files.add(df, fill_value=0, axis=1)
    
combined_files.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: This looks like it will work but when I run it, I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: I did update @gtomer code to match my updated variables - still no joy. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas?  @gtomer Thanks!

Comment: I have corrected the answer above

Comment: If I print(df) or df.to_excel, I see df is populated with data from one of the spreadsheets. I commented out the "combined_files" section 1st to test this.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, the file prints but only with one set of data -- not all combined but you pointed me in the right direction.  I will keep working on it.  I appreciate your help and your time!  John

Comment: I am not a developer, but Operations Manager for a non-profit.  I appreciate any help I can get and appreciate the help from @gtomer and others so far.  Here is a link to my Github with sample data: https://github.com/johnmillstead/BudgetRollUp/tree/main/completed

Comment: Please convert the XLS files to CSV

Comment: If I convert to CSV the files will need A LOT of cleaning-up to be usable.  I'm not sure that makes sense since I will have 50 - 65 files to process.

Comment: See updated answer after looking at your GitHub

Comment: Thank you so much! @gtomer I lost a little sleep last night trying to figure this out and have been working on reading manuals, trying solutions, etc.  I appreciate you taking the time to help out.

Comment: Glad to help. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function after you have read these excel files in pandas:

```py
combined_excels = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis = 0)
```

if you want to concat it vertically.